# Multiple buttons in the same form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, button

I have one simple `form` with two `buttons` inside. Each `button` has to redirect me on different `view` in my `controller`. I was looking for some examples over the net, found solutions and implemented them. Unfortunately, it isn't working for me.

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private MovieEntities db = new MovieEntities();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Button(ButtonName = "clickButton", ButtonValue = "Send")]
        public ActionResult Send()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Button(ButtonName = "clickButton", ButtonValue = "Reset")]
        public ActionResult Reset()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Index view:**

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomWizzardMVC.Models.MovieInfo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<h1>Insert informations</h1>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="button" name="clickButton" value="Send" />
    <input type="button" name="clickButton" value="Reset" />
}
```

**Send** and **Reset view** are just simple views with `<p>` tags inside.

I have **Button class** too:

```
public class Button : ActionNameSelectorAttribute 
    {
        public string ButtonName { get; set; }
        public string ButtonValue { get; set; }

        public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            return controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[ButtonName] != null && controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[ButtonName] == ButtonValue; 
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong in here? Also, if you know some other way to do the same functionality **without using jQuery**, please post some code :)

Comment: I'd recommend you to use `@Html.ActionLink()`-s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how it can be done.  `<input type="submit" value="Send" formaction="@Url.Action("Send","Home")" />` Just found out that `formaction` is the new `HTML5` attribute that specifies the URL of the form for the `HttpPost` action. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a form's target by it's action attribute.

So you can do this by changing your form's action attribute. You need to use client side script to do that.

An another option, you can send a value that contains user's option (like Option = "reset" or Option = "send"). And decide what view you need to go in your default view.

Comment: Found how it can be done.

`<input type="submit" value="Send" formaction="@Url.Action("Send","Home")" />`
Just found out that `formaction` is the new `HTML5` attribute that specifies the URL of the form for the `HttpPost` action. :)

Comment: nice, i didn't know that :)

Answer (score 0):

**Change your input type="button" to type="submit.**

`<input type="button" />` buttons will not submit a form - they don't do anything by default. They're generally used in conjunction with JavaScript as part of an AJAX application.

`<input type="submit">` buttons will submit the form they are in when the user clicks on them, unless you specify otherwise with JavaScript.

Comment: Check the post above, I wrote that I found how it can be done :) Basically, the same stuff as you wrote :)